# Load different config based on the result of a Service function in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

Is it possible in ZF2 to load a different config file (or just manually add an array to the existing config) based on a function in a Service (or model)?

To be more precise, I have a (third party) module that needs a bunch of custom settings from the config.

In one of my own modules, in `module.config.php` I have a custom config setting:

```
'my_custom_config' => array(
    'display_something' => true,
),
```

Then in an invokable service I have a function, say `isDisplaySomething()`, that will determine whether display_something is true or false.

My first try was to call that function in `getConfig()` of `Module.php` and then add it to the config as an array, but I can't figure out how to access the Service there.

Then I tried to overwrite Configuration in the `onDispatch()` in a controller, but I can't access the ServiceManager there (and it's probably not a very elegant solution anyway).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For dependencies on a value from config I would suggest you setup a factory to create your service. Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use My\Service\DisplayService;

/**
 * Factory for creating the DisplayService
 */
class DisplayServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create the DisplayService
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return DisplayService
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = array();
        if ($serviceLocator->has('config')) {
            $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        }

        // Default value in case nothing in config
        // An alternative is to throw an exception if no value found in config.
        $displaySomething = true;

        if(isset($config['my_custom_config'] && isset($config['my_custom_config']['display_something'])){
            $displaySomething = $config['my_custom_config']['display_something'];
        }

        // Use setter to set the value or use constructor dependency.
        $displayService = new DisplayService();
        $displayService->setDisplaySomething($displaySomething);

        return $displayService
    }
}
```

And then in your `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\Service\DisplayService' => 'My\Factory\DisplayServiceFactory'
    )
)
```

Now you can get your service from your service manager like this:

```
$serviceManager->get('My\Service\DisplayService');
```

and it will have your `$displaySomething` value.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of having a factory for the service. But I'm afraid this won't solve my actual problem. It's the third party module who needs one set of configs or another, based on a setting in the Service. The Service shouldn't read the config, but rather change it, if that's even possible.

Comment: @magnetronnie What module are you using? It is not very proper behavior to set or overwrite `config` values from within a service? Can you explain more in detail why this is necessary? It would also mean the `config` array can be different depending on whether the service is called or not. This sounds very strange. The idea behind the service `config` array is that it that it is static and that it can be cached. Dynamic content would mean you cannot cache your `config`. In a production environment caching is really necessary.

Comment: It's an asset manager module. I wasn't happy with the modules I found online so I wrote my own, loosely based on other modules and they all used a module config to set the modules settings and add the assets. I think you are right changing the config is probably not desirable behavior. I'll try to add some kind of way to change the asset module settings/assets from another model. The config can stay, but only acts as default values. Thanks for the help.